# Add column with average value grouped by column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace column value of dataframe with mean(*without zeros*) value of column grouped by another column.

Dataframe **df** is like:

```
ID | TYPE | rate
-------------
1  |    A | 0 <- Replace this
2  |    B | 2
3  |    C | 1
4  |    A | 2
5  |    C | 1
6  |    C | 0 <- Replace this
7  |    C | 8
8  |    C | 2
9  |    D | 0 <- Replace this
```

I have to replace values in rating where rating = 0:

```
df['rate'][df['rate']==0] = ?
```

with average value for that **TYPE**.

Average(*without zeros*) value for every type is:

> A = 2/1 = 2
>
> B = 2/1 = 2
>
> C = (1 + 1 + 8 + 2)/4 = 3
>
> D = 0 (*default value when there isn't information for type*)

Expected result:

```
ID | TYPE | rate
-------------
1  |    A | 2 <- Changed
2  |    B | 2
3  |    C | 1
4  |    A | 2
5  |    C | 1
6  |    C | 3 <- Changed
7  |    C | 8
8  |    C | 2
9  |    D | 0 <- Changed
```

Comment: Be careful with this `df['rate'][df['rate']==0] = ...`, always use this instead `df.loc[df['rate']==0, 'rate'] = ...`, see for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) the `rate` column in the dataframe, `GroupBy` the `TYPE` and [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) with the `mean`, which will exlude `NaNs`. The use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to replace the values in the masked dataframe:

```
ma = df.rate.mask(df.rate.eq(0))
df['rate'] = ma.fillna(ma.groupby(df.TYPE).transform('mean').fillna(0))

   ID  TYPE  rate
0   1    A   2.0
1   2    B   2.0
2   3    C   1.0
3   4    A   2.0
4   5    C   1.0
5   6    C   3.0
6   7    C   8.0
7   8    C   2.0
8   9    D   0.0
```

Comment: That... seems wrong, you just end up with essentially the mean everywhere.

Comment: OP wants to replace values where the `rate` is 0 with the mean of the corresponding group exluding 0s. That's what is being done here @IanS